# Should I install the AX88179 USB Ethernet Driver - or any other external driver?

Tags: macos, usb, driver

I try to avoid external drivers that require root permissions to install, as they might break regular functionality/integrity easily, yet it seems like a must to install them sometimes.

I bought a USB 3.0 HUB with an Ethernet port, it seems to use an AX88179 chip, a common one as I see, it doesn't get recognised automatically

Should I risk it and install the drivers or keep using the Wi-Fi instead and not fix something that's not broken?

Comment: I have just installed this driver and feel it's sketchy but I want to use ethernet so it's this or just wi-fi. I don't feel the answer below is a great one. Can U comment on how this driver has been for U?

Comment: Best to avoid it tbh, but I don't remember any issues, however, it's also a good idea to not use hubs with extra chips like this, as they consume more energy, and it caused old devices to do lots of 100% -> 99% -> 100% loops and fail their lipo's faster

Answer (score 1):

Should be safe, but make sure you have a backup to revert to - just in case.

Current drivers would appear to be v2.2, according to the [Asix](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131;71;112) site

[untested]

Comment: adding a comment, that you have not tried it would be nice :)

Comment: I could also add I don't even have any USB 3 ports ;-) but if you can't trust manufacturers' dedicated drivers, what can you trust? [Fair point, though - just joking]

Comment: Thank you, the reason is when dealing with drivers one can not be careful enough :) and you got a +1 from me.

Comment: Thank you too. I had mentioned a backup was a safety net - tbh, I'm so paranoid about backups mine are hourly on site & daily off-site - you can never be too careful.